# How to Get the Camera Roll Pictures using MediaLibrary in any Culture

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have been using some code to gather pictures directly from the `Camera Roll` album, but I am specifically using the album's name when gathering the photos. What I'd like to do is extend this into another language as well, but obviously their equivalent album on their device will not be of the same name. An example of what I am talking about is below

```
using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach (PictureAlbum album in library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums)
    {
        if (album.Name == "Camera Roll")
        {
            _pictures = album.Pictures;

            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

Intead of explicitly stating `album.Name == "Camera Roll"` in the If statement, how might I get access to this particular album on a device that is not set to an english speaking culture. For instance, a device in Spanish would have a different name correct? How do I call those same photos in the equivalent album?

Comment: I think that Camera Roll will be always the first album in the collection additionally to the same name in the different cultures. Just tested it in Russian.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, the string will stay the same no matter what language. But it is best to test it first by changing your phone's language.

I have seen it in many places and everybody confirms this is the only way to do it (and I agree it is not one of the best API design choices), so we will probably have to live with that.

Comment: Ok so, in code behind `Camera Roll` will remain the name of that particular album on any device in any language/culture settings? I'll test this in the emulator but, I know devices work different in some situations.

Comment: Yes. It stays the same, no matter what culture or language setting, I have not seen anyone saying that it doesn't.